# How to close a excel file after creating it in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am creating an Excel file using the PHPExcel library and it works fine using the following code:

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save($new_name);
```

When I try to access the Excel file from other web application, am getting the following error:
`File is used by other program`

How can I close `$objWriter` in PHPExcel to solve this issue?

Any help on this.

Comment: is there any locking strategy?

Comment: The file is always `closed` as soon as the script terminates, but should be closed at the end of the call to save() if you're writing to a `physical` file rather than a stream like php://output

Comment: Check if you have the same issue when you open it with excel.

Answer (score 8):

You can try to specifically destroy resources after the save, but this should automatically be covered when the script ends. The `disconnectWorksheets()` method might do the trick too.

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save($new_name);
$objPHPExcel->disconnectWorksheets();
unset($objWriter, $objPHPExcel);
```

Going off the [documentation](http://www.contao-docs.org/docs/PHPExcel/html/class_p_h_p_excel___i_o_factory.html), there doesn't seem to be a nice way of actually "closing" the resources.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... I tried to run this code still i am facing the issue...   But i noticed the excel file created by PHPExcel is not saved properly... When i open it and close , its is asking to save even though i haven't done any changes... is there any commit function available?

Comment: I updated the answer to include using the `disconnectWorksheets()` method which might help free up the resources. If that doesn't help, perhaps post a bit more of your code?

Comment: Also, depending on your needs, you can try using `'Excel2007'` instead of `'Excel5'`.

Comment: I am using header("Location:test_excel.php?sheet=".$sheet ); exit(); ... will it cause any issue...

Comment: If the file has been written successfully and all resources have been freed up, it shouldn't cause problems, no. If in doubt, you can try removing that redirect from your code and just manually test out the file.

Comment: When opening the created .xls in MS Excel it prompts to save the file for the first time alone, then after its not prompting. When i have done the save in MSExcel the file is opened by the web service, if its not saved, there is nullpoint exception when accessed by the another web service.

Comment: Check all the formulas in your workbook. If you have anything that automatically updates, there's your problem. Also check for links to external sources. It could also be due to Excel updating the file format - consider using `'Excel2007'` instead of `'Excel5'`.

Comment: I am using the formula fields, that is causing the problem.  Unless i open manually and save the excel... Is there any way to sort out this issue programmatically

Comment: I wouldn't think so. If they're formulas that update automatically, they will update every time the spreadsheet is opened, whether it's automatic or manual. Disabling automatically calculation would get around the issue, but you would lose the functionality! If the spreadsheet is being created and saved properly using PHPExcel, everything is fine with your code.

Comment: it is happening for me... if remove the formula field... every thing looks fine

Comment: I would still recommend trying `Excel2007` instead of `Excel5` and seeing if it's any different, but have a look through [this list](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/24766-excel-always-asks-save-even-without-making-changes-2.html#post2884846) of suggestions for what might be causing Excel to prompt a save...

Answer (score 3):

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save($new_name);
$objPHPExcel->disconnectWorksheets();// Good to disconnect
$objPHPExcel->garbageCollect(); // Add this too
unset($objWriter, $objPHPExcel);
```

I tried with above and resolved memory issue!